# Python Selenium button click with SVG and Span

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, svg, button, selenium-chromedriver

I spent a lot of time on a seemingly simple problem but I am still looking for answers.

Here is the output from print(browser.page_source) just so I am doing my path right.

This is the button that I am trying to click with Selenium with no luck at all. I have no experience with Selenium and SVGs. I am not sure SVGs even come into play here. I thought a simple xpath with .click(0 event should do it but no dice so far.

[image] [image]

```
<button type="button" disabled="" class=“kl-button kl-button-pri ce-blue-button kl—button-disabled">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 22 22” fill="none" stroke=“bluecolor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class=“school_search green_fields-search”>
      <circle cx="12” cy="12” r=“9”></circle>
      <path d="M17 19l-4.25-4.15"></path>
   </svg>
   School Finder<span class="green_fields_p”><span class="green_fields"></span></span>
</button>
```

This is what I tried so far.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
# browser.get('https://google.com')
browser.get(url)

# find_all = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='school_load']//div[2]//button[2]")
# find_all = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="LoadResults"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]')

# browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="ce-blue-button" and child::svg[@class="school_search green_fields-search"]]').click()

# find = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="kl-button kl-button-pri ce-blue-button kl—button-disabled"]')

find = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="ce-blue-button"]//*[name()="svg"][@class="school_search green_fields-search"]')
print(find)
find.click()

# browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button/*[name()="svg"][@class="school_search green_fields-search"]').click()
```

I got output as

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

or

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2f2ab3421ll4fd509ecbeb762bd11d8e", element="44d4ce11-5a26-412a-8md1-83c59plm7c12")>
```

No matter what I tried, I am unable to get the button clicked. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: click() exists on HTML elements only, are you trying to call it on an SVG element?

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: @RobertLongson : Wouldn't svg elements falls under web element  category ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue consists out of 2 separate problems.

1. The first issue is a NoSuchElementException. This error can occur when the page is not yet loaded but the `find_element` code is already executed and thus couldn't find the element.
   I recommend using WebDriverWait to wait for the element is loaded before looking for it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

xpath = '//button[...]'
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH)))

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
    
except TimeoutException:
    print('Waiting for the element to appear on the webpage has expired. Wrong xpath?')
```

2. The second issue you seem to have is not being able to click on the element. When this happens, you can always use ActionChains to move your mouse to a certain element and then click on that location.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = find_element(...)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to code you presenting in the question you are missing a wait.
You are trying to access the element before the page is loaded.
Please try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

find = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="ce-blue-button"]//*[name()="svg"][@class="school_search green_fields-search"]')))

print(find)
find.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a special way to locate the svg web element, Please use the below xpath

```
//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='“school_search']/..
```

There are basically 4 ways to click in Selenium.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='“school_search']/..").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='“school_search']/.."))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='“school_search']/..")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='“school_search']/..")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.